# Calculating age from a varchar column with discrepancies

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Hoping you had a restful Easter. Appreciate if you could advice/help me in the following. (Using Function/without function)

Below are my DataSet, Desired Output (With derived Age using the DOB specifications from the rules)

Your help is needed in (Please note that i looking for solution in MSSQL environment):-
1. **Coming up with Age field.** (I tried the following script but it didn't work as it is not dynamic enough to include all the DOB rules, i also attached an oracle script which worked as a reference for you guys)

```
SELECT 
[ID],
[DOB],
 'age' = DATEDIFF(HOUR,(CONVERT(date,(CASE WHEN ([DOB] like '99/%/%') THEN (REPLACE([DOB],'99','01'))
               ELSE [DOB] END),103)),GETDATE())/8766 
from [Sample]
```

**Sample_Dataset**

```
create table Sample (
  Id  Varchar (50),
  DOB Varchar (50))

  insert into Sample(Id, DOB)
  Values 
  ('38603', '24/02/1969'),
  ('38605', '22/09/1969'),
  ('36356', '17/03/1954'),
  ('36374', '17/05/1975'),
  ('36441', '17/08/1961'),
  ('1a', '10/05/9999'),
  ('1b', '10/99/9999'),
  ('1c', '99/99/9999'),
  ('2a', '--/--/1935'),
  ('2b', '00/00/1935'),
  ('2c', '88/88/1935'),
  ('2d', '99/99/1935'),
  ('3a', '10/--/1935'),
  ('3b', '10/00/1935'),
  ('3c', '10/88/1935'),
  ('3d', '10/99/1935'),
  ('4a', '--/09/1935'),
  ('4b', '00/09/1935'),
  ('4c', '88/09/1935'),
  ('4d', '99/09/1935')
```

**Desired output**

```
ID     | DOB        | Age (As of 05-03-2018; dd-mm-yyyy)      
38603  | 24/02/1969 | 49  --Everything is known      
38605  | 22/09/1969 | 48        
36356  | 17/03/1954 | 63        
36374  | 17/05/1975 | 42        
36441  | 17/08/1961 | 56    
1a     | 10/05/9999 |null --unknown year
1b     | 10/99/9999 |null
1c     | 99/99/9999 |null
2a     | --/--/1935 |82   --unknown day and month 
2b     | 00/00/1935 |82
2c     | 88/88/1935 |82
2d     | 99/99/1935 |82
3a     | 10/--/1935 |82   --unknown month but known year 
3b     | 10/00/1935 |82
3c     | 10/88/1935 |82
3d     | 10/99/1935 |82
4a     | --/09/1935 |82   --unknown day but known month 
4b     | 00/09/1935 |82
4c     | 88/09/1935 |82
4d     | 99/09/1935 |82
```

**Rules:-** 
As you can see in the above **5 scenarios** in the comments

1. Everything is known (use the stated DOB to calculate the age)
2. Unknown **Year** (put age as **null** as the year is known)
3. Unknown **day and month**  (Use **01/07** for the unknown dd/mm and the stated yyyy)
4. Unknown **month but known day** (Use **07** for the unknown **mm** and the stated dd/07/yyyy)
5. Unknown **day but known month** (Use **15** for the unknown **dd** and the stated 15/mm/yyyy)

**Solution in Oracle**

Creating a function first (Tried replicating this logic in T-SQL but unsuccessful, hence i am here)

```
create or replace function check_dt(in_date in VARCHAR2, in_format in VARCHAR2 default 'DD/MM/YYYY')
RETURN NUMBER
IS
V_DATE DATE;
V_STATUS INTEGER;
BEGIN

 SELECT TO_DATE(in_date,in_format)
 INTO V_DATECASE  
 FROM DUAL;

 V_STATUS := 0;
 RETURN V_STATUS;  
 EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
 V_STATUS := SQLCODE; 
         RETURN V_STATUS;
        END;

        select check_dt('11/30/2017') from dual;
        select TO_DATE('15/--/9999','DD/MM/YYYY') from dual;

select id, dob,
       case when check_dt(dob) = -1843 --not valid month, default it to July (07)
               THEN substr(dob,1,2)||'/07'||substr(dob,7,4) 
            when check_dt(dob) = -01847 -- day of month must between 1 and last day of month
               THEN '1/07/'||substr(dob,7,4)
            WHEN check_dt(dob) = 0 and to_date(dob,'dd/mm/yyyy') > sysdate
               THEN NULL
            WHEN check_dt(dob) = -0183 -- date not valid for month
               THEN '15/'||substr(dob,4)
            ELSE
               THEN dob 
            END New_dob
from SAMPLE;
```

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thank you very Much.

Comment: `mysql` <> `sql-server`. `mysql` does not use `tsql`. Can you please update your tags accordingly?

Comment: @Larnu: Thank you for noting it. I was thinking mssql. didn't read it properly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following. I used different CTE's to show you the progression towards obtaining the date of birth from your varchar DOB. I also changed the table to a temporary one.

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Sample') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Sample

create table #Sample (
  Id Int,
  DOB Varchar (50))

insert into #Sample(Id, DOB)
Values 
(38603, '24/02/1969'),
(38605, '22/09/1969'),
(36356, '17/03/1954'),
(36374, '17/05/1975'),
(36441, '17/08/1961'),
(119, '10/05/9999'),
(114, '10/99/9999'),
(132, '99/99/9999'),
(25125, '--/--/1935'),
(2323, '00/00/1935'),
(2512, '88/88/1935'),
(2156, '99/99/1935'),
(368, '10/--/1935'),
(34135, '10/00/1935'),
(3435, '10/88/1935'),
(3241, '10/99/1935'),
(4512, '--/09/1935'),
(4161, '00/09/1935'),
(4312, '88/09/1935'),
(456, '99/09/1935')

;WITH ParsedBirth AS
(
    SELECT
        S.Id,
        S.DOB,
        Year = SUBSTRING(S.DOB, 7, 4),
        Month = SUBSTRING(S.DOB, 4, 2),
        Day = SUBSTRING(S.DOB, 1, 2)
    FROM
        #Sample AS S
),
ParsedBirthInteger AS
(
    SELECT
        P.Id,
        P.DOB,
        Year = CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(P.Year) = 1 AND P.Year <> '9999' THEN CONVERT(INT, P.Year) END,
        Month = CASE 
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(P.Month) = 1 AND CONVERT(INT, P.Month) BETWEEN 1 AND 12 THEN CONVERT(INT, P.Month) 
            ELSE 7 END,
        Day = CASE 
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(P.Day) = 1 AND CONVERT(INT, P.Day) BETWEEN 1 AND 31 THEN CONVERT(INT, P.Day) 
            ELSE 15 END
    FROM
        ParsedBirth AS P
),
InferredBirth AS
(
    SELECT
        P.Id,
        P.DOB,
        InferredBirth = CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), P.Year * 10000 + P.Month * 100 + P.Day))
    FROM
        ParsedBirthInteger AS P
)
SELECT
    T.Id,
    T.DOB,
    T.InferredBirth,
    Age = (CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(),112))-CONVERT(char(8),T.InferredBirth,112))/10000
FROM
    InferredBirth AS T
```

Comment: This solution is very similar to mine, yet using some different approaches in detail. +1 from my side and one tiny hint: This relys on a fixed format like `dd/MM/yyyy` and would break on a value like `1/12/2000` or `12/1/2000`. But the given examples seem to be strict here...

Comment: @Ezequiel López Petrucci: Hello again. Thank you for trying to help me again. what is CTE? and also is #sample a dummy table in mssql just like dual is in oracle?

Comment: @Ezequiel: The age is only considering the Year. for ID=38605  | DOB= 22/09/1969 |Desired age should be 48 as birthday have not passed. Thank you for trying.

Comment: @Stephanie oh yeah, I corrected the Age calculation. CTE is Common Table Expression and its the "subqueries" that are declared with "WITH" (just a form to avoid nesting subqueries, amongst other uses). Tables that start with # are called temporary and are automatically dropped when the session dies (disconnects). In SQL Server, the "dual" doesn't exist, you can omit the FROM clause in SQL Server in that case (like in `SELECT 999 AS Number`).

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci: Good morning, thank you for the explanation. i think it did not work on (ID=36356, DOB='17/03/1954') because it is on the 17th of the month of march not the first. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @Stephanie, someone who was born in 1954-03-17 is now 64 years old, as the query says. This works as expected. You can also check the correct date of birth in the `InferredBirth` column. The query compares dates until current date, if you want a previous date then you need to replace `GETDATE()` for a particular date in the `Age` calculation.

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci: Kindly read the note on the desired output. ID= 36356  | DOB= 17/03/1954 | Desired Age= 63 not 64 as the cut off date is 05-03-2018

Comment: As I said, change the reference date (change `GETDATE()` for `CONVERT(DATE, '2018-03-05')` . You can't expect us to do everything for you :P

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci: Thank you for helping. Just a silly one. so i change the GetDate convert in the last portion and not ParsedBirthInteger or InferredBirth right?

Comment: Yes, all expressions up to `InferredBirth` are to deduce the persons' birth. The last part, the rest between ints at the `Age` column, is when we compare the current date (`GETDATE()`) with the allegedly date of birth of the person.

Answer (score 2):

SQL SERVER

```
SELECT id,
       CASE WHEN YEAR(GETDATE())-REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(DOB), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(DOB)) - 1)) > = 0 
            THEN 
              YEAR(GETDATE())-REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(DOB), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(DOB)) - 1))
          ELSE 
             NULL
       END AS Age
FROM Sample
```

Solution For Your Question

```
WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT id,
       CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(DOB), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(DOB)) - 1))) = 1  THEN
                REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(DOB), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(DOB)) - 1))
            ELSE
                NULL
        END
       AS Year,
       CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(DOB, CHARINDEX('/', DOB) - 1)) = 1 THEN
                 LEFT(DOB, CHARINDEX('/', DOB) - 1)
            ELSE
                NULL
       END AS DAY,
       CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(DOB,CHARINDEX('/',DOB)+1, CHARINDEX('/',DOB,CHARINDEX('/',DOB)+1) -CHARINDEX('/',DOB)-1)) = 1 THEN
            CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DOB,CHARINDEX('/',DOB)+1, CHARINDEX('/',DOB,CHARINDEX('/',DOB)+1) -CHARINDEX('/',DOB)-1) >= 1 AND SUBSTRING(DOB,CHARINDEX('/',DOB)+1, CHARINDEX('/',DOB,CHARINDEX('/',DOB)+1) -CHARINDEX('/',DOB)-1)  <= 12 THEN
                SUBSTRING(DOB,CHARINDEX('/',DOB)+1, CHARINDEX('/',DOB,CHARINDEX('/',DOB)+1) -CHARINDEX('/',DOB)-1)
                ELSE 
                NULL
            END
            ELSE
                NULL
        END AS MONTH
FROM Sample),CTE1 AS
(
  SELECT id,
         year,
         month,
         CASE WHEN DAY IS NOT NULL THEN
              CASE WHEN DAY >= 1 AND DAY <= DAY(EOMONTH(year+'-'+month+'-01')) THEN
                DAY
              ELSE
                NULL
              END  
         ELSE NULL
         END AS Day
  FROM CTE
)
,CTE2 AS
(
SELECT id,
           CASE WHEN YEAR IS NULL
                       THEN NULL
                     ELSE
                       CASE WHEN DAY IS NULL AND MONTH IS NULL THEN '01/07'
                            WHEN MONTH IS NULL AND DAY IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(day AS VARCHAR)+'/07'
                            WHEN MONTH IS NOT NULL AND DAY IS NULL THEN '15/'+CAST(MONTH AS VARCHAR)
                            ELSE CAST(day AS VARCHAR)+'/'+CAST(MONTH AS VARCHAR)
                       END
                       + '/'+CAST(YEAR AS VARCHAR)
                END
        AS DOB
FROM CTE1
)
SELECT id,DOB,
   CASE WHEN DOB IS NOT NULL
        THEN 
          CASE WHEN DATEDIFF (day,  CONVERT(DATE, DOB, 103),CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),103)) >=0
           THEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF (day, CONVERT(DATE, DOB, 103), CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),103)) / 365.2425)
           ELSE
              NULL
          END
      ELSE 
         DOB
   END AS Age
FROM CTE2
```

**DEMO LIVE**

> http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3714d33cacb02c3fce4f0868c9d0990b

Comment: Hi there, this doesn't give the desired age as stated above. It simple calculates 2018-yyyy.

Comment: Check 2nd Solution

Comment: Shankar The age is only considering the Year. for ID=38605 | DOB= 22/09/1969 |Desired age should be 48 as birthday have not passed. Thank you for trying

Comment: Check Now @Stephanie

Comment: I think /365.2425 It didn't work on (ID=36356, DOB='17/03/1954') because it is on the 17th of the month of march not the first. May i know how do you find out which denominator to use for each month? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

- It is a very bad idea to store a date in a culture dependant string format.
- It is a very bad idea to use *magic values* (`9999` meaning "no year").
- Is is a most dangerous, bad idea to mix this!

The following code will transform your values to the format you should use to store this actually. You can build your age-logic from here, but I'd really recommend you, to use this approach to clean up this mess and store your data properly!

```
DECLARE @sample TABLE(
  Id VARCHAR(10),
  DOB VARCHAR (50))

  INSERT INTO @sample(Id, DOB)
  VALUES 
  ('38603', '24/02/1969'),
  ('38605', '22/09/1969'),
  ('36356', '17/03/1954'),
  ('36374', '17/05/1975'),
  ('36441', '17/08/1961'),
  ('1a', '10/05/9999'),
  ('1b', '10/99/9999'),
  ('1c', '99/99/9999'),
  ('2a', '--/--/1935'),
  ('2b', '00/00/1935'),
  ('2c', '88/88/1935'),
  ('2d', '99/99/1935'),
  ('3a', '10/--/1935'),
  ('3b', '10/00/1935'),
  ('3c', '10/88/1935'),
  ('3d', '10/99/1935'),
  ('4a', '--/09/1935'),
  ('4b', '00/09/1935'),
  ('4c', '88/09/1935'),
  ('4d', '99/09/1935');
```

--The query will split your string on the `/` and try to cast the values to `int`:

```
WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT Id
          ,DOB 
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(DOB,'/','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[1]','varchar(10)') AS DOB_Day
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(DOB,'/','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[2]','varchar(10)') AS DOB_Month
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(DOB,'/','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[3]','varchar(10)') AS DOB_Year
    FROM @sample
)
,Casted AS
(
    SELECT Id
          ,DOB
           --below SQL-Server 2012 you can use `CASE` with `ISNUMERIC` instead of TRY_CAST
          ,TRY_CAST(DOB_Day AS INT)  AS CastedDay 
          ,TRY_CAST(DOB_Month AS INT)  AS CastedMonth
          ,TRY_CAST(DOB_Year AS INT)  AS CastedYear 
    FROM Splitted
)
,Checked AS
(
    SELECT Id
          ,DOB
          --You can use further logic to get the month's days correctly (instead of the plain 31)  
          ,CASE WHEN CastedDay BETWEEN 1 AND 31 THEN CastedDay ELSE NULL END AS TheDay
          ,CASE WHEN CastedMonth BETWEEN 1 AND 12 THEN CastedMonth ELSE NULL END AS TheMonth
          ,CASE WHEN CastedYear BETWEEN 1900 AND 2100 THEN CastedYear ELSE NULL END AS TheYear
    FROM Casted
)
SELECT *
FROM Checked;
```

The result

```
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| Id    | DOB        | TheDay | TheMonth | TheYear |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 38603 | 24/02/1969 | 24     | 2        | 1969    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 38605 | 22/09/1969 | 22     | 9        | 1969    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 36356 | 17/03/1954 | 17     | 3        | 1954    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 36374 | 17/05/1975 | 17     | 5        | 1975    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 36441 | 17/08/1961 | 17     | 8        | 1961    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 1a    | 10/05/9999 | 10     | 5        | NULL    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 1b    | 10/99/9999 | 10     | NULL     | NULL    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 1c    | 99/99/9999 | NULL   | NULL     | NULL    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 2a    | --/--/1935 | NULL   | NULL     | 1935    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 2b    | 00/00/1935 | NULL   | NULL     | 1935    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 2c    | 88/88/1935 | NULL   | NULL     | 1935    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 2d    | 99/99/1935 | NULL   | NULL     | 1935    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 3a    | 10/--/1935 | 10     | NULL     | 1935    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 3b    | 10/00/1935 | 10     | NULL     | 1935    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 3c    | 10/88/1935 | 10     | NULL     | 1935    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 3d    | 10/99/1935 | 10     | NULL     | 1935    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 4a    | --/09/1935 | NULL   | 9        | 1935    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 4b    | 00/09/1935 | NULL   | 9        | 1935    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 4c    | 88/09/1935 | NULL   | 9        | 1935    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
| 4d    | 99/09/1935 | NULL   | 9        | 1935    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: understand on the bad idea but what to do if it's legacy data. hence, it's out of hand. It is a practice to not change the raw data of the sourcefile as it is data collected especially in industries such as research. But yes, thank you for your heads up. This method is too much work. But thank you.

Comment: @Stephanie How can this be *to much work*? You cannot interpret this as a date. So you have to 1) split the string to get the values separately, 2) check if the value can be casted to an `int`, then 3) check whether the values are within a given range (against *magic values*). There is no faster way... Don't change the raw data, but use an approach like the above to store valid information additionally. Use this while you import this data (from somewhere), within an `insert/update trigger` or as an UDF to fill a persistant computed column. You should not computed against your raw data...

Comment: Yeah i agree, when it is dirty data. Steps have to be taken first to clean the data before manipulating it to be desired value. Thank you.